# Julia benchmarking DSP.jl, CUDANative and CuArrays

Tags: julia, gpu, benchmarking, julia-gpu

I'm experimenting with DSP.jl - the `conv()` method, in particular. I'm using `CUDANative` and `CuArrays` to create arrays to be arguments to `conv()`, so that the cuda versions of `fft()`, etc. will be used. I'm using `BenchmarkTools` to get performance data. I find that the Julia runtime complains about running out of CPU or GPU memory under odd circumstances. Here's my test setup:

```
using CUDAdrv, CUDAnative, CuArrays
using DSP
using FFTW
using BenchmarkTools

N = 120
A = rand(Float32, N, N, N);
B = rand(Float32, N, N, N);
A_d = cu(A);
B_d = cu(B);

function doConv(A, B)
    C = conv(A, B)
    finalize(C)
    C = []
end

t = @benchmark doConv($A_d, $B_d)
display(t)
```

Here's an example of the odd behavior I mentioned. If I set `N` to 120, my script runs to completion. If I set `N` to 64, I get the "out of memory" error:`ERROR: LoadError: CUFFTError(code 2, cuFFT failed to allocate GPU or CPU memory)`. I can run the smaller case first, get the error, then bump `N` to the larger value and have the script complete successfully.

Is there something I should be doing differently to prevent this from happening?

Comment: Could you please provide the hardware specification you are running this code on + versions of the libraries?

Comment: @sophros We've moved on in a different direction since then, so I'm not able to recover that info.